# Reference request for Intuitionism

Tags: reference-request, philosophy

I need to write an essay on Intuitionism for my Philosophy of Science class, and I'm looking for books which cover the following topics:

- Brouwer's Intuitionism, from both a philosophical and mathematical point of view
- Constructive Mathematics

I have already read [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0631195440) book, but I'm looking for something more specific. I'm after books that can be consulted easily, without extensive background in logic or set theory. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Constructive Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/) at Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy has many resources at the bibliography. But I highly recommend [Gnomes in the Fog: The Reception of Brouwer's Intuitionism in the 1920s (Science Networks. Historical Studies, 28)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764365366) and the two volume of Brouwer's biography:

- [Mystic, Geometer, and Intuitionist: The Life of L. E. J. Brouwer Volume 1: The Dawning Revolution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198502974)
- [Mystic, Geometer, and Intuitionist: The Life of L. E. J. Brouwer: Volume 2: Hope and Disillusion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198516207)

Comment: Thanks, the book about the reception of Intuitionism is especially helpful. Do you know of any books in the form of a monograph on Intuitionism?

Comment: A formal treatment is given in [Constructivism in Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=constructivism+in+mathematics+troelstra&source=bl&ots=omBXkbrpzI&sig=45jlg3Z4Gs82cZu0niPS3ZrObBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TeQWT9zbBJPZiQLW0p3HDw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=constructivism%20in%20mathematics%20troelstra&f=false); also try [Elements of Intuitionism](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Intuitionism-Oxford-Logic-Guides/dp/0198505248) by Michael Dummett